# How do I enable the Timer_A0 module for the following CCS IDE MSP432P401R Launchpad microcontroller code?

Tags: c

I have the following code for a task that requires me to use the following code to use the Timer_A0 module in the CCS IDE to control the speeds of the motors for a robot that uses the MSP432P401R launchpad as the control unit. How do I initialize the Timer_A0 module in the C programming code below?:

```
#include "driverlib.h"
#include "mechrev.h"

/* Define macros and function prototypes if needed */
#define BTN1_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P1,GPIO_PIN1
#define BTN2_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P1,GPIO_PIN4
#define ENB1_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P1,GPIO_PIN6
#define ENB2_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P1,GPIO_PIN7
#define PWM1_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P2,GPIO_PIN4
#define PWM2_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P2,GPIO_PIN5
#define PWM3_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P2,GPIO_PIN6
#define PWM4_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P2,GPIO_PIN7
#define BMP0_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4,GPIO_PIN0
#define BMP7_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4,GPIO_PIN7
#define BMP2_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4,GPIO_PIN2
#define BMP6_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4,GPIO_PIN6
#define BMP3_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4,GPIO_PIN3
#define BMP5_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4,GPIO_PIN5
#define BTN3_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4, GPIO_PIN0 | GPIO_PIN7
#define BTN4_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4, GPIO_PIN2 | GPIO_PIN6
#define BTN5_PIN            GPIO_PORT_P4, GPIO_PIN3 | GPIO_PIN5

/* Define configuration structs if needed */

/* Declare global variables if needed */
int i = 0;
uint32_t counter = 0;

/* Main program */
void main(void)
{
    /* Stop Watchdog Timer */
    WDT_A_holdTimer();

    /* Call the mechrev_setup function included in the mechrev.h header file */
    mechrev_setup();

    /* Initialize GPIOs P1.1 and P1.4 for PushButtons (S1 and S2 switches) */
    MAP_GPIO_setAsInputPinWithPullUpResistor(BTN1_PIN);
    MAP_GPIO_setAsInputPinWithPullUpResistor(BTN2_PIN);

    /* Initialize GPIOs P1.6 and P1.7 for Motor Driver IC Enable Pins */
    MAP_GPIO_setAsOutputPin(ENB1_PIN);
    MAP_GPIO_setAsOutputPin(ENB2_PIN);

    /* Initialize GPIOs P2.4, P2.5, P2.6 and P2.7 for PWM functionality  */
    MAP_GPIO_setAsInputPin(PWM1_PIN);
    MAP_GPIO_setAsInputPin(PWM2_PIN);
    MAP_GPIO_setAsInputPin(PWM3_PIN);
    MAP_GPIO_setAsInputPin(PWM4_PIN);

    /* Initialize Timer A0 to generate PWM signals */

    (Timer_A0 module needs to be initialized here)  

    /* Declare local variables if needed */

    /* Call the initialization grading macro */
    MACRO_LAB4_INIT();

    while(1)
    {
    /* Design a Polling process to detect PushButtons press and adjust the PWM duty cycles 
 accordingly */
        if (MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue(BTN1_PIN) == GPIO_INPUT_PIN_LOW)
        {
        if(i == 1)
        {
            TA0CCR1 = 999;
            TA0CCR2 = 0;
            TA0CCR3 = 999;
            TA0CCR4 = 0;
        }

        if(i == 2)
        {
            TA0CCR1 = 1998;
            TA0CCR2 = 0;
            TA0CCR3 = 1998;
            TA0CCR4 = 0;
        }

        if(i == 3)
        {
            TA0CCR1 = 3000;
            TA0CCR2 = 0;
            TA0CCR3 = 3000;
            TA0CCR4 = 0;
        }

        for (i=0; i<10000; i++); // switch debouncing
    }

    else if (MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue(BTN2_PIN) == GPIO_INPUT_PIN_LOW)
    {
        if(i == 1)
        {
            TA0CCR1 = 0;
            TA0CCR2 = 999;
            TA0CCR3 = 0;
            TA0CCR4 = 999;
        }

        if(i == 2)
        {
            TA0CCR1 = 0;
            TA0CCR2 = 1998;
            TA0CCR3 = 0;
            TA0CCR4 = 1998;
        }

        if(i == 3)
        {
            TA0CCR1 = 0;
            TA0CCR2 = 3000;
            TA0CCR3 = 0;
            TA0CCR4 = 3000;
        }


        for (i=0; i<10000; i++); // switch debouncing
    }

    else
    {
        TA0CCR1 = 0;
        TA0CCR2 = 0;
        TA0CCR3 = 0;
        TA0CCR4 = 0;
    }

        /* Note: Call the event grading macro after changing PWMs */
        MACRO_LAB4_EVENT();
}
}

void PORT4_IRQHandler(void)
{
    /* Check the interrupt status */

uint32_t status;
status = MAP_GPIO_getEnabledInterruptStatus(GPIO_PORT_P4);

if (status)
{
 if(MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue(BMP0_PIN) == GPIO_INPUT_PIN_LOW || 
 MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue(BMP7_PIN) == GPIO_INPUT_PIN_LOW)
    {
        i = 1;
        counter++;
    }

else if (MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue(BMP2_PIN) == GPIO_INPUT_PIN_LOW || 
MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue(BMP6_PIN) == GPIO_INPUT_PIN_LOW)
{
    i = 2;
    counter++;
}

else if (MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue(BMP3_PIN) == GPIO_INPUT_PIN_LOW || 
MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue(BMP5_PIN) == GPIO_INPUT_PIN_LOW)
{
    i = 3;
    counter++;
}

}

else
{
counter++;
}

MACRO_LAB3_EVENT();

/* Clear the PORT4 interrupt flag */

MAP_GPIO_clearInterruptFlag(GPIO_PORT_P4, status);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can configure the timer itself, you need to initialize a struct that you will use to configure the timer (there are slight differences in the values needed for upmode, updownmode, continuous mode). You can download the Driverlib Manual [MSP432 DriverLib for MSP432 devices](https://www.ti.com/tool/download/MSP432DRIVERLIB#downloads) which contains detailed use of the timers.

Another very helpful tutorial is [Interrupts, Timers &  Debugging](https://lectures.tik.ee.ethz.ch/es/labs/lab2_solution.pdf)

You are mixing both Driverlib names and register-level names in your code. That's fine, just make sure you keep the nomenclature straight and don't confuse register access names with user variables, etc..

Now, to configure your timer `Timer_A0`, you need to initialize a structure to use configuring the time. An example for configuring the timer in up mode would be:

```c
/* TimerA0 UpMode Configuration Parameter */
const Timer_A_UpModeConfig upConfigTA0 =
{
  TIMER_A_CLOCKSOURCE_ACLK,                 /* ACLK Clock 32 KHz  (uint_fast16_t clockSource) */
  TIMER_A_CLOCKSOURCE_DIVIDER_1,            /* Rollover in 1 sec  (uint_fast16_t clockSourceDivider) */
  ACLKMAX,                                  /* 32767 ticks        (uint_fast16_t timerPeriod) */
  TIMER_A_TAIE_INTERRUPT_DISABLE,           /* Rollover TAIE      (uint_fast16_t timerInterruptEnable_TAIE) */
  TIMER_A_CCIE_CCR0_INTERRUPT_ENABLE,       /* CCR0 CCR0IE        (uint_fast16_t captureCompareInterruptEnable_CCR0_CCIE) */
  TIMER_A_DO_CLEAR                          /* Clear Timer        (uint_fast16_t timerClear) */
};
```

Above the timer is configured to use `ACLK` (32KHz), but you can use `SMCLK` as well.

Within your code you will need to configure the timer using the struct above. For example:

```c
    /* Configuring TimerA0 for Up Mode */
    MAP_Timer_A_configureUpMode (TIMER_A0_BASE, &upConfigTA0);
```

You can also configure/set any additional timer interrupts you plan to use, e.g.

```c
    /* Set Capture/Compre Register 3 */
    MAP_Timer_A_setCompareValue (TIMER_A0_BASE, MPUCCR, MPUCCRTICKS);

    /* enable CCRn compare interrupt */
    MAP_Timer_A_enableCaptureCompareInterrupt (TIMER_A0_BASE, MPUCCR);
```

At this point you have your timer and interrupts configured and read to use, but the timer is **not yet started**. Before the timer and interrupts are active, you must start the timer itself. Generally, you do this right before you enter you program loop (the `while (1) { ... }` loop). That way you can configure other peripherals without having your interrupts starting to fire until you complete all your configuration. After everything is configured, start the timer:

```c
    /* Starting the Timer_A0 in up mode (just before while loop) */
    MAP_Timer_A_startCounter (TIMER_A0_BASE, TIMER_A_UP_MODE);
```

With every timer, you have two primary interrupt service routines provided by driverlib. The first handles `CCR0` and is named `TA0_0_IRQHandler()` for `Timer_A0` (or `TA1_0_IRQHandler` for `Timer_A1`, etc..)). It's declaration is:

```c
/**
 * Timer A0 CCR0 Interrupt
 */
void TA0_0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    ...
}
```

All other interrupts associated with the timer use `TA0_N_IRQHandler()`. For instance for capture/compare registers `CCR1` - `CCR5` and the `TAIE` rollover interrupt (one clock-cycle after `CCR0`). It has a declaration of

```c
/**
 *  Timer A0 Interrupt Handler (remaining interrupts)
 */
void TA0_N_IRQHandler(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Since you are looking to control a robot arm, I presume you will be using the timer for PWM control. The tutorial covers that fairly well.

I placed complete example using Timer_A to driver PWM on pastebin at [MSP432 PWM Control of Tri-Color LED](https://pastebin.com/4NSQGptV). That shows the use of upmode to drive PWM.

*DO NOT OVERLOAD THE INTERRUPT FUNCTIONS WITH FUNCTION CALLS OR COMPUTATIONALLY INTENSIVE CODE.* They are effectively signal-handlers. You want to avoid time consuming processing in the ISR (Interrupt Service Request) functions. Instead, the best approach is to set a flag in the interrupt function to complete processing in your program loop, e.g.

```c
    /* Starting the Timer_A0 in up mode */
    MAP_Timer_A_startCounter (TIMER_A0_BASE, TIMER_A_UP_MODE);


    while (1)
    {
        if (btn1pressed) {          /* respond to button presses by calling button handlers */
            btn1_handler();
        }
        if (btn2pressed) {
            btn2_handler();
        }
        if (getmpudata) {           /* retrieve data from MPU9250 */
            get_MPU_data();
        }
        if (getmagdata) {           /* retrieve data from AK8963 */
            get_MAG_data();
        }
        ...
```

Above, each of the variable names contained in the `if (...)` statements are simply `bool` variables set in the interrupt functions that tell your program it's time to process whatever function they trigger. Processing is done in `main()` not in the interrupt functions. The reason being that heavy computation in the interrupt function can cause the interrupt to fire again before your processing is complete (your code takes more time than the time between interrupts). That is a sure-fire way to cause your program to crater.

The driverlib user's guide is a goldmine for configuring all the peripherals. See if you can get your timer working and look at the tutorial link I provided above. Let me know if you have further questions.